# FQL query: How to select users from the same country

Tags: facebook-fql

How do I write the FQL query to select users from the same country?

As hometown_location is not indexable, we cannot use hometown_location as the index.

So, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could (if it wasn't an excessive number of users that you were querying) just get all of them with their `hometown_location` attribute and then filter it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already noticed that FQL won't let you compare using that column, then you will need to load each of the user's info you are looking at comparing into some array in your code.  Then loop thru that array comparing the hometown_location.